# How to access AWS S3 bucket logging in with Google and Cognito User/Identity Pool

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-js

I'm using the AWS Cognito Enhanced (Simplified) Flow to get the Cognito Identity Credentials providing the idToken received after logging in with Google sign-in api:

```
export function getAWSCredentialWithGoogle(authResult) {

    if (authResult['idToken'] != null) {
      AWS.config.region = 'eu-central-1';
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',              
            Logins: {
                'accounts.google.com': authResult['idToken']        
            }
        })

        return AWS.config.credentials.getPromise()
            .then(
                function(){

                    return getAWSCredentials(AWS.config.credentials);
                },
                function(err) {

                }
            )

    } else {
              console.log('no auth code found!');
           }

}
```

I get the:

> accessKeyId:"ASIAXXXXXX",
>   secretAccessKey:"ta4eqkCcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
>   sessionToken:"xxxxxxxxx...etc..."

Then I try to upload a picture to an S3 bucket passing the above received accessKeyId and secretAccessKey.
But I receive this error result:

> `InvalidAccessKeyId`The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.ASIAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

This is how I set up the AWS S3 (managed) policy (the resource policy for the bucket is the default one) to access progammaticaly the bucket:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxxxx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxxxx/users"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxxx/users/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxxx/users/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

this policy has been attached to an IAM role with the following trust relationship:

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
   "Condition": {
     "StringEquals": {
      "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-central-1xxxxxxxxxxx"
     },
     "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
      "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
     }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I've properly configured the Federated Identity Pool to use this role, and added Google as an OpenID Connect provider.
I also configured my Cognito Identity Pool to accept users federated with my Cognito User Pool by supplying the User Pool ID and the App Client ID.

I would like to to give to any Google sign-in authenticated user, access to the S3 bucket and have read/write permission to his own directory.